# how to specify lambda template parameter type explicitly

Tags: c++, c++20

With C++20 you can now do the following:

```cpp
auto x = []<typename T>(T x){};
```

this is fine with template argument deduction, but if I have a non-type template parameter, e.g.

```cpp
auto x = []<std::size_t N>(){};
```

how do I specify N?

```
x<1>();
```

doesn't work, instead it's handled as `lt` comparison between x and 1.

Comment: That dupe doesn't apply; it's answers are specifically for C++17 and `auto` parameters. This is a C++20 question.

Comment: @sweenish: Check the answer there. It gives the `operator()` form of the function call operator, which accepts template arguments. I.e. `x.operator()<1>()`.

Comment: @sweenish, nothing has changed in C++20 in that respect. `x.operator()<N>();` is the answer.

Comment: Note that even non-type template parameters can be deducible: `[]<std::size_t N>(std::array<double,N> &d) {…}` can usefully find a base-class subobject, for example.